# Substituir conteúdo de uma tabela por outra?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

O meu caso é o seguinte:

Tenho duas tabelas `TAB1` e `TAB2`; as duas tabelas têm a mesma estrutura: (id, nome, apelido).

Gostaria de substituir o conteúdo da `TAB1` para a `TAB2`. Tudo que existe na `TAB2` deve ser apagado e substituído pelo conteúdo da `TAB1`.

Gostaria também de fazer este processo apenas numa requisição ao banco de dados.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Eu nao sei nada de `php` por isso vou deixar outra pessoa ajudar

Comment: Pk André. Se meter o código que tem neste momento a sua pergunta será mais aceite pela comunidade.

Answer (score 3):

```
truncate table tab2;
insert into tab2 (SELECT * FROM tab1);
```

Comment: Tudo numa unica instrucao ? Gostaria de fazer isso num unico request !

Comment: @PkAndré Voce pode fazer isso num único request. Desde que meta os comandos em batch.

Comment: @BrunoCosta poderias se possivel ilustrar com um exemplo ?

Comment: @PkAndré No `rdbms` os comandos sao sempre executados em batch (se nao me engano). Por isso o problema só existe quando voce acede ao seu banco de dados na aplicacao. Só posso explicar se voce editar a sua pergunta com o sistema de base de dados em questao e a linguagem que está a usar.

Comment: @BrunoCosta estou usando php !

Comment: @PlanwebInterativa, o uso de TRUNCATE TABLE me parece melhor do que o DELETE, pois não gera log. É claro que só pode ser utilizado caso não exista algum procedimento trigger associado a DELETE na tabela TAB2 e não existam outras tabelas apontando (chave estrangeira) para TAB2 (se o engine for InnoDB);

Answer (score 3):

Não está claro se quer saber somente os comandos SQL ou se quer criar a conexão com um script PHP.

Portanto, de uma forma genérica,

Primeiro exclua os dados existentes:

`DELETE FROM TAB2;`

Em seguida execute `INSERT INTO TAB2 (SELECT * FROM TAB1);`

Pode fazer isso usando um MySQL front-end como o PHPMyAdmin.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*imagem ilustrativa

Não pode fazer as suas queries ao mesmo tempo pois o MySQL impede queries múltiplas por definição padrão. É possível mudar esse padrão mas implica em questões de segurança.

Importante relevar que se for apenas substituir os dados de uma tabela com os dados de outra tabela poderia apenas aplicar o REPLACE INTO, sem uso do `truncate` ou do `delete`.

```
REPLACE INTO TAB2 (SELECT * FROM TAB1)
```

Só isso já basta.

Mas para um caso específico onde quer limpar "vestígios" da tabela `TAB2` que não existem em `TAB1`, o melhor mesmo é excluir tudo antes de proceder com o `INSERT`.

Comment: pelo que entendi e pela conversa que tive com `AP` ele quer mesmo fazer um script `php` para fazer isso. Pode ser que ele esclareca melhor.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Estou a fazer requets com PHP ! No entanto nao vejo como fazer delete e depois insert au mesmo tempo.

Comment: Não pode fazer as suas queries ao mesmo tempo pois o MySQL impede queries múltiplas por definição padrão. É possível mudar esse padrão mas implica em questões de segurança. Deixe da forma como está e execute uma por vez. Não precisa de 2 requisições. Uma única requisição basta (get, post).

Comment: @DanielOmine o que ele quer é executar as queries em `batch` nao "ao mesmo tempo". Ou seja, segundo a pergunta diz `apenas numa requisição ao banco de dados`

Comment: Percebi isso Bruno, mas achei ambíguo quando ele diz “request php”.